# Play sounds in sequence when each has ended

Tags: flash, actionscript, audio, actionscript-2

I have 3 sounds that I would like to play, they are in my library.
I can play any of of them using `soundName.start(0,1)` with the code below:

```
firstSound = new Sound();
firstSound.attachSound("Sound1");
secondSound = new Sound();
secondSound.attachSound("Sound2");
thirdSound = new Sound();
thirdSound.attachSound("Sound3");
```

The trouble i am having is, how can i know when sound1 has finished playing so i can then play sound2 and then sound3 immediately after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate frame number of the sound ending using the framerate and sound lenght.
After that you can call `AddFrameScript(frameNum, function)` and add code to play next sound.

Comment: That sounds rather complex, i wouldn't know where to begin with that. I take it there is no event for this kind of thing then? I tried firstSound.addEventListener("complete",myListener); var myListener = new Object();
 myListener.complete = function() {
  trace("done");
 };
but this does not fire.

Comment: this is how to get sound duration:

var c_snd:Sound = new Sound();
c_snd.attachSound("linked_sound");
trace('duration: ' + ((c_snd.duration/1000)<<0) + 's');

divide this by your frame rate, and you'll get the frame number where it ends.Let's call it "some_frame";
use some_movie_clip.AddFrameScript(some_frame, your_sound_start_function).

I assumed that you start 1st sound at frame 0, and in main movie clip.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the code, i think AddFrameScript is AS3 but i might be able to get it working with some form of delay thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there exists a way in AS2, using onSoundComplete:

```
soundFX = new Sound();
soundFX.loadSound("sound.wav", true);
//or, if your sound is already in the library, 
//use soundFX.attachSound("librarySoundInstanceName");
soundFX.onSoundComplete = function() 
 {
//DO some action
/////////////
gotoAndStop("new12");
die();
newLevel();
}
```